# Most used Strings in IntelliJ

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea

Is there a way to detect, if any hard-coded string is repeated more than ***x*** times in the whole project?

Let's say I have a project with multiple folders and classes and I have a separate class called `Constants`, where I store all my project constants. Since the project is getting bigger, it will be nice to have a possibility to detect repeated strings in the project. Of cource, it could be also manually done, but probably it exists already in IntelliJ or somewhere else.

***Example:***

instead of:

```
class A {
    String dog = "dog";
    String cat = "cat";
    String animals = dog + cat;
}

class B {
    String dog = "dog";
    String horse = "horse";
    String animals = dog + horse;
}
```

I am trying to make:

```
class A {
    String cat = "cat";
    String animals = DOG + cat;
}

class B {
    String horse = "horse";
    String animals = DOG + horse;
}

class Constant {
    static final String DOG = "dog";
}
```

It is oversimplified, but I hope the point is clear.

Comment: why would you need something like this, and why should this be ide-specific?

Comment: @Stultuske I think I have described my use case, and yes, it should not be ide-specific if it doesn't depends from ide

Comment: if these are indeed constants, you should not care about this - since they are part of the constant pool anyway.

Comment: read about [Java String Constant Pool](https://study.com/academy/lesson/java-string-constant-pool-concept-mechanism.html). JVM does this work for you. after reading, is your question still actual?

Comment: (It is an antipattern IMHO to just collect strings, but understandable.) With _code analysis_ magic hard coded values are marked. So even 1 time constants should declared. And static final Strings can be found easily; sort them and voilà.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search part can be accomplished in four ways.
However only the second one is able to extract the new constant automatically.

- Using the *Find in path* dialog, using a configuration similar to the below one.
  All the entries will be listed under *Preview*.

[image]

---

- Using the *Extract constant* functionality (limited to the current file).

[image]

A new popup will appear, with the option *Replace all occurrences*

[image]

Using the designated shortcut (e.g. `Ctrl+Alt+C`) or `Enter`, another dialog will appear, and you'll be able to see the occurrences count.

[image]

---

- Using a specific inspection, which is *Duplicate String literal*.
  You'll be able to run it via `Analyze > Run inspection by name`.

[image]

A new dialog will appear, which lets you customize the search criteria

[image]

---

- Structural Search ([docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html)).
  Unfortunately I'm not knowledgeable about it.

Comment: `Using the Extract constant functionality` that's the thing I was looking for

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov remember that might be limited to the current file only. I'll see if I can find a way for it to work everywhere.

Comment: Oh, I will test it. If yes, that is sad

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov in case I'll open an issue on YouTrack, and I'll link it here.

Comment: It seems to work only in one class. It doesn't seacrhing in the whole project

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov see updated answer, at the bottom. However there is no "magic quick fix".

Comment: That is also a great feature, but it is searching duplicates within a one class

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov no, you can choose. It will open a dialog. You can run it on the whole project.

Comment: I mean it will scan the whole project, but every class in the project will be scanned separately

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov yes, unfortunately, yes. I can't think about other ways

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov your best bet is the *Replace in path* dialog. Similar to the *Find in path*. That will let you replace everything with a static property, if necessary. You'll have to create that property by yourself, unfortunately.